# Special characters not being read, even though file is set to UTF-8

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, charset

The special characters in my HTML files are not being read in Firefox (works fine in Safari and Chrome), even though I have the character set set to UTF-8. See the "A Parlatë e A Memorjë" seciton: https://memoriaelinguagrumentina.org/index.html

And this is the meta tag I'm using:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

I've read through a dozen other questions in this forum with similar problems, but none of the solutions apply to my situation. I don't want to use HTML elements, because it would make editing a nightmare. And I'm not using anything other than HTML and CSS on this page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your original HTML file is UTF-8? And if you look in a UTF-8 editor does it look right? (I assume Chrome and Safari are smarter and correct double encodings)

Comment: If I have the meta tag as shown above with charset="UTF-8", doesn't that make the file UTF-8? And I've been doing my editing in Atom, which I have set to UTF-8. The text displays correctly in the editor, just not in Firefox.

Comment: For the first question: no, the meta tag tell that the browser should interpret the file as UTF-8. But so you should have the original file in UTF-8. It helps to distinguish two concepts: what it is really the file (so the bytes, so the encoding), and how should I read it (and really also the third: the semantic: UTF-8 vs. Unicode) -- Note: a lot of editor are smart: UTF-8 as default, but if it fails, they will try to detect the encoding) -- In any case, it seems you solved the problem, right?

Comment: I think I have. I broke the long meta tag I had into to, like this: ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">``` I'm not sure why, but it made a difference. Just one more question. What do you mean by "have the original file in UTF-8"? How do I do that? Is there a setting in my code editor or a tag I should be using?

Comment: Yeah, check the encoding on the code editor, and ev. tell him to save as UTF-8 (without BOM). Note: Web is now UTF-8 (by default). Your broken text had two characters per accented character, so it makes me thinking you had a double encoding (UTF-8 text read as Latin1 and then converted to UTF-8) [I rule out the option: browser read a UTF-8 file as Latin1, because of your tags, and the default utf-8 on browsers]. Good editors should be able to help you transcoding and viewing text in other encodings. (which help to figure out errors)